# How to set listener to a MATLAB object's structure's field

Tags: matlab, oop, listener

I have a MATLAB object which is similar to:

```
classdef myObj < handle

properties (SetObservable)
    % NOTE: we want this to be a struct, as written, its not
    myStruct
end

methods
    function self = myObj(fieldVal)
        self.myStruct = fieldVal;
        % WANT: self.myStruct.myField = fieldVal;

        %  add listener to update if change to self.myStruct
        % WANT: add listener to update if change to
        % self.myStruct.myField
        addlistener(self, 'myStruct', 'PostSet', @self.callbackFnc);
    end

    function callbackFnc(self, varargin)
        fprintf(['self.myStruct is now ', num2str(self.myStruct), '\n'])
    end

end

end
```

Which has a listener to a property of an instance (optimistically named `myStruct`).  This gives:

```
>> tempObj = myObj(3);
>> tempObj.myStruct = 4;
self.myStruct is now 4
```

How can I set the listener to a field of `self.myStruct` rather than `self.myStruct` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do directly. You can only attach a listener to a property itself, not to a field of the property (if the property is a struct).

I would try to do something slightly different, using the `set` function for the `myStruct` property to detect which field was being set, and then firing a regular event rather than a property event:

```
classdef myObj2 < handle

properties
    myStruct = struct('myField', []);
end

events
    myFieldChanged
end

methods
    function self = myObj2(fieldVal)
        self.myStruct.myField = fieldVal;
        addlistener(self, 'myFieldChanged', @self.callbackFnc);
    end

    function set.myStruct(obj, val)
        oldProp = obj.myStruct;
        obj.myStruct = val;
        if obj.myStruct.myField ~= oldProp.myField
            notify(obj,'myFieldChanged')
        end
    end

    function callbackFnc(self, varargin)
        fprintf(['self.myStruct.myField is now ', num2str(self.myStruct.myField), '\n'])
    end

end

end
```

Hope that suggestion helps!